# Closure of the real line on $\mathbb R^2$ standard topology

Tags: general-topology

What is the interior and closure of this set A on the standard topology on the real plane?

Let $A= \{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$

Answer I came up with:

$\mathrm{int}(A)= \emptyset$ as there does not exist a basic open set that contains an element in $A$ and contained in $A$.

$\mathrm{Cl}(A)= \mathbb R^2$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're right on target with the first conclusion. What reasoning did you use for the second?

Comment: There does not exist a closed rectangle or a union of closed rectangles that contains the entire real line that is smaller than the entire plane. Let cl(A) not include a point y. By definition of closure, there exists an open set who contains y and whose intersection with cl(A) is empty. However, this would imply there exists another point whose is not in cl(A). Therefore cl(A) must be the entire plane.

Comment: You should include that in your post by using the "edit" button. Many people don't read the comments, and downvote posts that don't include enough context in the body of the question.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!

Comment: For any point $(a,b)$ not in $A$, and therefore $b\neq0$, the ball $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:\ (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<b^2\}$ doesn contain any point of $A$.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your comment that you are not using the correct definition of closure. There does indeed exist "a union of closed rectangles that contains the entire real line and is smaller than the entire plane", for example the union of the closed rectangles $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} ([n,n+1] \times [-r,+r])$, for any choice of $r > 0$. But even knowing that, it's kind of a backwards way of understanding $\text{Cl}(A)$.

In any topological space $X$, for any subset $A \subset X$, the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed subset containing $A$, equivalently the intersection of all closed subsets containing $A$. As a special case, if you happened to know that $A$ was already a closed subset of $X$, then $A = \text{Cl}(A)$.

So let's apply this definition to $X = \mathbb R^2$ and $A$ = $\{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$. The point is that $A$ is closed, because $\mathbb R^2 - A = \{(x,y) \mid y \ne 0\}$ is open (which I'm sure you can verify).

Therefore, $\text{Cl}(A) = A$.

Comment: OH! I see what you mean! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Also, it is a good and standard practice on stackexchange web sites that if you like at least one answer to your question, you choose the one you like the most and you accept it by clicking on the checkmark.